# Enable SSL on Spring actuator using chain file

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot application running on SSL programmatically using TomcatServletWebServerFactory where we set the following from configuration file:

```
proto.setSSLCertificateKeyFile(classLoader.getResource(certificateKeyFile).getPath());
                proto.setSSLCertificateFile(classLoader.getResource(certificateFile).getPath());
                proto.setSSLCertificateChainFile(classLoader.getResource(certificateChainFile).getPath());
```

However, i would like to enable on SSL on the actuator endpoint too. I found online that we do this using the following in application.properties:

```
management.server.ssl.enabled=true
management.server.ssl.key-store=
management.server.ssl.key-password=
```

This is not working in my case as i need to reuse the above certificate. If i add an additional connector to TomcatServletWebServerFactory  programmatically, it throws an error as already bind port as if actuator have different tomcat connector. How can i programmatically enable SSL on actuator while providing the certificate files as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing my programmed configuration and used the following:

```
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:name.pfx
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
```

without using SSL of actuator: management.server.ssl.xxx configuration